# Tableau JS API: How to get the filter value "All" if set in the filters

Tags: tableau-api

I am relatively new to using the tableau js api, I am trying to save the filters user applies to a dashboard in my application for further processing,For example, I have a filter with following values `"All", "Texas", "Colorado", "Arkansas".`

I am trying to find if the user has modified any filter and only save the filters which user has changed. When i use `getAppliedValues` i am only getting the values `"Texas", "Colorado", "Arkansas"`. How do i also get the string `"All"` back if its set.

Have been trying to check API for ways to access it but have not found one. Any help on this would be great.

we are using `tableau-2.min.js`

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who will land on this post, We recently upgraded the tableau server version to 2019.3.1 and see that the the JS API has a new method introduced called `getIsAllSelected`, which returns a boolean value based on if All is set on the filter or not.

At the time of writing this the documentation does not have a reference to it, but I am sure it would be added soon.

Thanks.